# I have a question about javascript data processing

Tags: javascript, object

for example :

`let array2 = [[{"Aaa":111}],[{"bbb":222}],[{"ccc":333}]];`

I am a beginner, How can I turn it into?

`[{"Aaa":111},{"bbb":222},{"ccc":333}]`

Comment: `array2.map(([e]) => e);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try mapping it like this:

```
array2 = array2.map(i=>{
  return i[0]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the javascript `map` function like this:

```
array2.map(x => x[0]);
```

[Learn more about the `map` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)